# Are there examples of PTMs that add different chemical groups (and mass) to different amino acids?

Tags: proteins, amino-acids

I'm talking about [this type of post-translational modifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posttranslational_modification#PTMs_involving_addition_of_smaller_chemical_groups). What I'm interested in is not whether some modifications can only occur on specific amino acids (that's clear), but if the nomenclature has examples of addition of slightly different chemical groups to different amino acids known under the same name.
Thanks.

Comment: Not clear about what you're asking. Are you asking if there is a class of PTM that describes the addition of a variety of chemical groups to a variety of amino acids?

Comment: Well, yes. Of course I don't expect this variety of groups to be diverse; maybe just a single deviation for a single amino acid.

Comment: The term "methylation" may be what you're looking for, if I understand your question correctly. A CH3 group can be added to one, two, or all three nitrogens on arginine's side chain, for example, potentially resulting in slightly different chiral conformations.